# Toggle letter casing in Javascript Sentence

Tags: javascript, string, case, toggle

I have a string which has lower and upper case letters
I need to convert the upper case letters to lower case, and lower case letters to upper case.
Basically toggle all the characters in the sentence

Answer (score -1):

```js
function toggleCase(sentence) {
  return sentence
    .split("")
    .map((el) => {
      if (el.toLowerCase() === el) {
        return el.toUpperCase();
      } else {
        return el.toLowerCase();
      }
    })
    .join("");
}
```

Input:
`They counTed them aNd were suRpriSed to fiNd that nOt one Lamb of tHe Great fLock of sEven huNdred waS miSsing`

Output:
`tHEY COUNtED THEM AnD WERE SUrPRIsED TO FInD THAT NoT ONE lAMB OF ThE gREAT FlOCK OF SeVEN HUnDRED WAs MIsSING`